# Converting multiple JOINS to json using JSON AUTO

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have the following SQL query.

```
SELECT quote.id,
       lines.id
        
FROM Quote quote

INNER JOIN Quote_Line as lines
    ON quote.id = lines.quote_id

FOR JSON AUTO
```

As expected it correctly returns the following JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "lines": [
      {
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now i am trying to extend this output with another 1-to-1 JOIN (Quote to Quote_Customer). How do i write this JOIN to get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "customer": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "lines": [
      {
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried adding a simple `LEFT JOIN Quote_Customer customer ON quote.id = customer.quote_id`, but this adds a nested `customer` object inside every `lines`-object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use FOR JSON AUTO is a good tip too, it's less error-prone to always build the json explicitly by using subqueries

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use a correlated subquery in the `SELECT`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Quote (ID int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.QuoteLine (ID int,
                            QuoteID int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer (ID int,
                           QuoteID int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Quote (ID)
VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO dbo.QuoteLine (ID,QuoteID)
VALUES(1,1),(2,1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Customer (ID,QuoteID)
VALUES(1,1);
GO

SELECT Q.ID,
       (SELECT ID
        FROM dbo.Customer C
        WHERE C.QuoteID = Q.ID
        FOR JSON AUTO) AS Customer,
       Lines.ID
FROM dbo.Quote Q --Aliasing a table called quote as quote doesn't make any sense
     INNER JOIN dbo.QuoteLine AS Lines ON Q.ID = Lines.QuoteID
FOR JSON AUTO;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Customer;
DROP TABLE dbo.QuoteLine;
DROP TABLE dbo.Quote;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. But what if i want to use the customer in a WHERE clause?

Comment: What about it, @JonasLittau ? You can add more clauses to the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

try to run below query

```
SELECT quote.quote_id,
       (select quote_id from Quote_Customer where quote.quote_id = quote_id  For json auto)customer,
       lines.quote_id
       
FROM Quote quote
INNER JOIN Quote_Line as lines
    ON quote.quote_id = lines.quote_id
FOR JSON AUTO
```

you can get below output:

```
[
  {
    "quote_id": 1,
    "customer": [
      {
        "quote_id": 1
      }
    ],
    "lines": [
      {
        "quote_id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "quote_id": 2,
    "lines": [
      {
        "quote_id": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```